# How to find coordinates of a point on a 3D cylinder in Cartesian system if any one point on cylinder and dimensions of cylinder are known?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider a cylinder of known dimensions inserted in 3D cartesian space. I know the cartesian coordinate of one point located on the surface of cylinder. Using this information I want to find out the coordinates of other points of the cylinder. Please help me with this.

Comment: It can be done. You need to know more than just one point.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is underdetermined, since every rotation of the cylinder you seek around the given point is a valid solution, too